# Which is more correct, faster, and safer: if(isset($var)){ do foo } OR if($var){ do foo }?

Tags: php, html

I am in the process of creating an associative array called `errMsgs[]` that will hold error messages that correspond to a particular `<input>` field error. Which form of testing `errMsgs[]` is more correct, faster, and safer? Does either method have important advantages or disadvantages?

Contact Form Code Snippet: Focus --> The third `<td></td>` in a table with three columns as in ...

```
(column1)    (column2)     (column3)  <----Focus of this code snippet.
---------    ----------    ----------
```

Where **column1** is a `<label></label>` inside of a `<td></td>`.
Where **column2** is an `<input />` control inside of a `<td></td>`.
Where **column3** is an empty `<td></td>`, filled conditionally based on the `errMsgs[]` associative array.

### Skeleton 1

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input />
        </td>
        <td>
<?php
            if($errMsgs['firstName'])
            {
                echo $errMsgs['firstName']; //This element is not from user input. 
            }
?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

### Skeleton 2

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input />
        </td>
        <td>
<?php
            if(isset($errMsgs['firstName']))
            {
                echo $errMsgs['firstName'];  //This element is not from user input.
            }
?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Escaping and coding style issues aside, which skeleton is superior? Which have you used in the past? I want to use the best way.

Comment: `isset` is the correct way to do this, using just `if($errMsgs['firstName'])` will throw an `Undefined index` notice. (Your examples are missing the `$` sign btw.) And speed is no concern for such a minimal operation anyway.

Comment: `if($var)` would throw a notice if the variable is not defined in the first place, whereas `if(isset($var))` would not. I'd personally use `!empty($var)`, though.

Comment: @CBRoe Thanks, I was stuck in bash mode for a moment!

Comment: @Amal Murali. I think empty() permits too many possibilities compared to isset(). If the number zero is the element, I do not want that to evaluate to FALSE.

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: @deceze Empty is not even in the running here. It's too broad and not the right way to do it. isset() is a language construct, not a function.

Comment: An empty array already returns false inside of if()

Comment: I love how people are always grouping the terms "more correct", "faster", and "safer" together when asking comparison questions as if the three concepts went hand-in-hand.

Comment: I posted the link to that article because it explains in detail what `isset` does and when it should be used. Yes, it also covers `empty`, can't hurt you to learn about that too.

Comment: I'm sure it can't hurt someone to learn about it. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You could try it.

`if($errMsgs['firstName'])` will return a notice when the key `firstName` doesn't exist. So use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) instead.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I have been  doing this on my white board. White boards tend not to give error messages!

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge: I don't know what a white board is, but if you're talking about PHP, you can [enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) to have these errors reported.

Comment: @AmalMurali A white board is short for a dry erase marker board. I am aware of error reporting. I used it in the development versions of my php.ini.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge: Note that it's also possible to the same thing with  `array_key_exists()` - might be more readable when dealing with arrays :)

Comment: @AmalMurali That would probably be a more expensive way to do it. `isset()` is a language construct, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. The language construct `isset()` is the way to go here.